# ¿Se puede leer elementos de un array fuera de un foreach?

Tags: php

Mi duda es la siguiente: Imagiros la siguiente situación:

Tabla en la base de datos llamada juegos, con las columnas de id_juegos, descripción, nombre...

Mediante foreach recorro y muestro los juegos. Se presume que $context['juegos'] muestra todos los datos de la tabla juegos.

```
function showId(){
foreach($context['juegos'] as j){
echo $j[id_juegos];
}
}
```

Con el siguiente fragmento de código mostraría todas las ids de los juegos. Ahora imaginaros que en esa función showId() necesito volver a hacer uso de ese foreach, ¿me mostraría en esa función la id de los juegos si está fuera del foreach?

Es decir:

```
function showId(){
foreach($context['juegos'] as j){
echo $j[id_juegos];
}
//Aquí el foreach acaba
echo $j[id_juegos]; //¿Me mostraría esto?
}
```

Una vez acaba el foreach he hecho un echo de lo mismo, la id de los juegos, ¿fuera de este foreach me lo imprimiría?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Y por qué no pruebas y ves qué pasa?

Comment: Antes de realizar una pregunta, considera investigar un poco, esta pregunta ya tiene respuesta, por lo que si fueses buscado un poco la fueses encontrado sin duplicarla. Saludis 

Answer (score 0):

Te daría error ya que intentas utilizar la variable `j` fuera del contexto donde la has definido, en este caso, solo la puedes utilizar dentro del bucle.